# permutations function using c code

Tags: c

I have written a program which prints all the permutations of a given string. But it was printing some weird things. The code goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
  int j;
  if (i == n)
    printf("%d\n", a);
  else
  {
    for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
    {
      swap((a+i), (a+j));
      permute(a, i+1, n);
      swap((a+i), (a+j));
    }
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  char a[100];
  gets(a);

  int k;
  k=strlen(a);
  permute(a, 0, k-1);

  system("pause");
}
```

It was printing some numbers instead of given string.. plz help

Comment: *Please* fix the indentation, this is way less readable than it should be.

Comment: This isn't your immediate problem, but, never ever use `gets`.  Terrible things will happen if someone types more than 100 characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is your problem:

```
 printf("%d\n", a);
```

should be

```
 printf("%s\n", a);
```